# Manual save missing, only autosave available

Tags: xbox-360, nba2k14

I'm asking on behalf of my brother, who has a problem with his copy of NBA 2k14 for Xbox 360.

In `My Career` mode, there are no options to save manually. The game just saves automatically after matches. I assumed that is the way the game works, but he swears that a friend of his has a "save" option in My Career menu, between "options" and "quit". He wants to create multiple manual saves in case he screws up a match.

Is there some option enabling manual saves?

Hidden somewhere deep, is there a trick that we've missed ?

Update: This is his friend's picture:

[image]

Comment: I have never known NBA2K console games to offer this sort of functionality.  I strongly suspect your brother's friend is telling the truth and/or the friend isn't playing on an xbox.

Comment: Does Save/Quit actually allow you to make a manual save? That sounds like it would just autosave and quit.

Answer (score 1):

This is an non-existant function.

As Ramhound says, this hasn't been in previous NBA2K games and still isn't

I think your brothers friend is lying

Comment: I've added a picture in my edit.

Comment: It is possible to manually save the game between matches on the PC version.  Is the friend in question using the PC or 360 version?

It's entirely possible that the two versions are identical but only having played one of them, I cannot be sure.